# Simple Calendar using Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to make a simple Calendar using Carbon https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon?

I am new with dates and not really sure how to go about it. Would it be easier to use the PHP calendar class? I am using Laravel 4 to accomplish this so was hoping using Carbon would be easy way to make one.

Comment: You should probably be a little more descriptive and objective about your problem.

Comment: I am just trying to make a base layout for a calendar. If I could just see how to make a current month calendar that starts at the first day of the month I could manage from there. Sorry for not being descriptive

Comment: Your question is very vague and difficult to provide a specific answer. But generally I would use Carbon, as it is very powerful and provides lots of good tools to use. Plus Laravel4 Eloquent already supports Carbon.

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can, it is quite simple to manipulate Carbon to create a simple HTML display of a month.

```
    $today = Carbon::today();

    echo '<h1 class="w3-text-teal"><center>' . $today->format('F Y') . '</center></h1>';

    $tempDate = Carbon::createFromDate($today->year, $today->month, 1);



    echo '<table border="1" class = "w3-table w3-boarder w3-striped">
           <thead><tr class="w3-theme">
           <th>Sun</th>
           <th>Mon</th>
           <th>Tue</th>
           <th>Wed</th>
           <th>Thu</th>
           <th>Fri</th>
           <th>Sat</th>
           </tr></thead>';

    $skip = $tempDate->dayOfWeek;


    for($i = 0; $i < $skip; $i++)
    {
        $tempDate->subDay();
    }


    //loops through month
    do
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        //loops through each week
        for($i=0; $i < 7; $i++)
        {
            echo '<td><span class="date">';

            echo $tempDate->day;

            echo '</span></td>';

            $tempDate->addDay();
        }
        echo '</tr>';

    }while($tempDate->month == $today->month);

    echo '</table>';
```

The output will look something like this:
[image: Html Calendar]

Comment: How would you go about removing the first entries that show last month's ending days in the first week of the month?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Putting it here if someone needs it:

`if ($today->month != $tempDate->month)`

Answer (score 0):

As people said in comments: a little vague, but I'll assume you need to create a calendar and do your things with it.

Yes you can use Carbon to help you manage date and time, but you better not start this from scratch, you can do it by using (and helping to grow, if possible) a Laravel 4 Calendar Package :)

https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelCalendar

Answer (score 0):

To me, Carbon is about parsing and displaying dates...it's an extension of the DateTime class. To create a calendar, you would still need to roll your own methods that build out the calendar. No need to reinvent the wheel as there are plenty of simple calendar scripts floating around the Internet. Depending on how it fits in with your project, you could go with the earlier suggestion of including a Laravel 4 Calendar package...or, you could go a different route altogether.

I would suggest going client-side for the calendar creation part, and have your PHP serve up the event data through Ajax requests. Adam Shaw has a pretty nice jQuery plugin called FullCalendar found here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/  or https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar

I would definitely recommend looking at the demos. Dropping FullCalendar into your Laravel 4 project is no different than adding it into any other project. Load jQuery, and then load FullCalendar. Check out the basic usage page: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/

Just thought I would throw this out there as one more option.

Comment: I agree with @fletch. fullcalendar is a great plugin that is simple to use and delivers a great looking, easily customizable and functional calendar straight out the box.